What happens if the Subscriber goes down - will the t-logs keep accumulating on the publisher in Transactional Replication?
I am trying to consider all the options before setting up transactional replication on my 2008R2 server to 2012 distribution server to 2012 Subscriber server. All the three servers are on FULL recovery mode. Log backup is taken every 15 minutes and full backup is taken daily everyday on all the three server databases used in replication. We want to use the subscriber as a reporting server. Publisher is our main OLTP database.
I am not using 'Sync with Backup' on Publisher and Distributor as I dont want latency by setting publisher to 'Sync with backup' as the transactions will only be replicated to Distributor when they are backed up at Publisher (which is done after every 15 min on my Publisher) and I dont want transactions to build up on Publisher by setting 'Sync with backup' on Distributor as the transactions will only be truncated from publisher when they are backed up at Distributor.
Now my questions are:

what will happen if the distributor or the subscriber goes down, will the transactions keep building up on my publisher (which is scary) ?

Will the commands (to get replicated) be queuing up on Publisher? How can I setup the retention period?



what will happen if the distributor or the subscriber goes down, will the transactions keep building up on my publisher (which is scary) ?
I assume 'transactions' means 'transaction log size' in this question.
If the distributor database goes down, the transaction log on the publisher will not get truncated and will keep growing.
Does replication affect the size of the transaction log?

Merge replication and snapshot replication do not affect transaction
log size, but transactional replication can. If a database includes
one or more transactional publications, the log is not truncated until
all transactions relevant to the publications have been delivered to
the distribution database. If the transaction log is growing too
large, and the Log Reader Agent is running on a scheduled basis,
consider shortening the interval between runs. Or, set it to run in
continuous mode. If it is set to run in continuous mode (the default),
ensure that it is running.

If the subscriber database goes down (and the distribution database is not on the same server), transactions will remain intact in the distribution database. How long it will keep the transactions depends on the Subscription Expiration value in the publication properties. The default is 72 hours, and this is adjustable. You can manually disable the distribution cleanup job if the subscriber database is not up before the expiration period. Once the latency falls below the expiration value, enable the cleanup job.
Will the commands (to get replicated) be queuing up on Publisher? How can I setup the retention period?
As mentioned above, if your distribution database is offline, the Transaction log will not get truncated (irrespective of the database recovery model) until the drive fills up. Suppose the distribution database is not online before you run out of transaction log space, you must remove replication and reestablish (with a new snapshot) it when it is back online. Otherwise, your publisher database will be unusable due to a lack of transaction log space.
